# How to reverse animate?

Tags: animation

For example when I record a rig walking and then I'd like to make it walk backward so how can I do that without much effort

Comment: See: [How do I animate time?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/)

Comment: Note that most natural walk cycles are not identical or 'flipped' forwards/backwards.  For a quick thing this'll probably work fine, though.

Comment: Or for a starting movement that can be later tweaked.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can flip the animation around by actually inverting your animation data in your animation editor.

1. Go to your dope sheet editor.
2. Set the current frame to the beginning of the animation (probably frame one)
3. Select the frames you want to reverse. Press <kbd>S</kbd> and type -1
4. Move the inverted animation back to where it is supposed to be positioned (using <kbd>G</kbd>)
5. Play back the animation!

When you're scaling the frames by negative one, you are really just reversing the animation. Similar to turning a shirt inside-out.

Comment: This is great! I've never tried that before. I just noticed too that the cursor line acts as the zero if you scale and drag.

Comment: Yes, by default all keyframes will scale around the cursor.

Comment: thank you. I've been trying to do this in many ways.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to reverse F-Curve key-frames, the **NLA editor** has a reverse option you can enable non-destructively per-strip. The NLA editor allows you to work with your animations in a *non-linear* manner; this allows you to repeat, scale, and reverse them, among other things.

In the NLA editor, press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the sidebar, then enable *Reversed* in *Active Strip* → *Playback Settings*.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is to render your animation, then go to the video sequence editor. Add your rendered images or movie, press <kbd>N</kbd> and go to the options in the filter section and check the option to play the active clip backwards. Go back to VSE press control <kbd>F12</kbd> (to sequence render, again), with the backwards box checked and this will render your animation in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on Lindsay's answer (which is excellent): In *Blender VSE* the option to reverse the clip is now in the N-panel under *Strip > Video > Reverse Frames* in Blender 4.0.2.