# Cell fracture explosion with followed by reform of the object?

Tags: animation

How can I explode an object then have them come back to form the original object. Kind of like going back in time.

The object is cell fractured into many peaces and it uses a ball object to explode it out. But how do I make the exploded pieces come together to original form?

[image]

Comment: See, [How to reverse animate](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/how-to-reverse-animate)

Comment: Yea I read but the problem is that there are no keyframes, which could be reversed. I guess it's my second gap how to make keyframes from blender animation simulation.

Comment: Bake the simulation to keyframes using the rigid body tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what your asking:

1. You can bake the rigid body action by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>, then searching for *Bake Action*. This will convert the rigid body simulation to an actual animation for the object.
2. Trim off the extra animation (when the objects fall forever):

   [image]
3. Duplicate the remaining keys, press <kbd>S</kbd> (scale), then type -1. This will flip the keys.

   [image]
4. Position them after the original keys:

   [image]

And you get:
[image]

Comment: Note that there is another way to bake rigid-bodies, with the *Rigid body tools* panel in the *Tool shelf*. Also note that *Bake action* can also be accessed in *3D view > Header > Object > Animation > Bake Action*

Comment: I did all that you wrote but I it didn't worked.
I created sphere, add particles and explode and than Bake action but when I delete modifier and start action in NLA editor it didn't work. If I didn't delete modifier and add this action again and reverse it this isn't work too. If I did all that you wrote it isn't work too. Tell me please, may be I did something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To bake rigid body action go to *Object > Rigid Body > Bake* to keyframes. Then it should work.