# What is the relation between Time Remapping, FPS, and the number of frames?

Tags: animation

I just needed my animation to be a little bit faster so I set the time remapping options to be:

Old = 100

New = 125

I need my output video to be **24 fps**. Do I need to change the number of frames in the timeline (the end value)?

Comment: Related: [How to animate time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1053) and [render at a higher framerate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22870) and [how to stretch frames of animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5054) and [calculate speed/duration for animataion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49563)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ratio of 100/125 means you want to stretch your action by a quarter, it keeps the exact same action but plays it 1/4 slower (and not faster!).

Note that the *Time Remapping* values dont affect the duration of the rendered movie, the *Timeline* still does it.

Let say your action finishes at the end of your *Timeline*. In the case of a slowed action, if you want to see the full action, and don't want it to be cut off by a quarter, you'll also need to increase the *Timeline* length by a quarter.

If you want to speed up your action by a quarter you need to set a ratio of 100/75, in that case your action will be finished at 75% of the rendered movie, you can either let it as it is (the last quarter will be still), or cut off 1/4 of your timeline, or cut off the last 1/4 of the rendered movie.

In both case you don't have to change the fps, *Time Remapping* precisely allows you to ignore the fps!