# Inserting frames in between current frame

Tags: animation

I, unknowingly, set my frame at multiple of one on timeline, and drew in each frame accordingly. I want to change it to multiple of 10 frame.

Comment: use time remaping https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html?highlight=time%20remapping#time-remapping and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189535/what-is-the-relation-between-time-remapping-fps-and-the-number-of-frames

Comment: or `A` `S` `10` ?