# Is there a way to automatically adjust keyframes to accommodate change in fps?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I have several animations that I would like to change from 30 to 60 fps and I'm wondering if there is a Blender tool or add-on that will proportionally adjust all the keyframes in a project to accommodate a change in fps?

In my perfect Blender world, when I change a project's fps, there would be a option to "Adjust All Keyframes Proportionally." Yes please!

As it is, despite tutorials I can't make heads or tales of Time Stretching; the best I have been able to do is select all keyframed objects, select the corresponding keyframes in the dope sheet, then use the Scale transformation tool  <kbd>S</kbd> and drag. That still obliges me to do some math and futzing around to get the keyframes aligned properly.

This seems like something that Blender should be able to do itself. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.10, Windows 11

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/47429/42221) answer your question?  (use time remapping)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/22870/how-to-render-an-animation-at-a-higher-framerate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5054/how-to-stretch-120-seconds-of-animation-over-270-seconds