# How does one animate time in the VSE?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor, nla-editor

I'm trying to move between slow motion and normal motion on a video/audio strip smoothly, but am having problems animating this.  I've tried [Individual objects and Entire scene and Time Remapper addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/how-do-i-animate-time)  but cannot get it to work.

When i try using the NLA editor for to control the speed of an individual video strip, i dont seem to find the check box Animated Strip Time

I would like to see a video screen cast of how one does this on a video strip.

Comment: Can you post .blend files, or at least more detailed explanations showing how those methods don't work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly went wrong?

Comment: To alter sound, change the audio strip's "pitch".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the VSE, the "multiply speed" value of a "Speed" effect strip **can't be animated**. You'll have to :

- uncheck the "Stretch to input strip length" box,
- check the "Use as speed" box,
- set the "Speed Factor" value to 1 (so the video will be played at normal speed)
- animate this value as you need:

  - greater than 1, playback will be faster,
  - between 0 and 1 the playback will be slower.

You may have to click the "Refresh Sequencer" button to see the result.

*Note that the sound won't be affected by this effect strip. I don't know if you can time-remap a sound in Blender.*

[image]