# How can I get a bullet-time effect (slow motion) in the BGE?

Tags: animation, game-engine, physics

I'd like to transition from normal speed to slow-motion on certain events, such as a keypress.

Is it possible to [animate time](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1053/599) in the game engine?
If so, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This functionality has [just been added](https://developer.blender.org/rBaae93ae4c6c13e2b30ba272e24354dd020880868). It will be in 2.77, until then it's only available in [development builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599).

> - getTimeScale(): Get the time multiplier between real-time and
>     simulation time. The default value is 1.0. A value greater than 1.0
>     means that the simulation is going faster than real-time, a value lower
>     than 1.0 means that the simulation is going slower than real-time.
> - setTimeScale(time_scale): Set the time multiplier between real-time
>     and simulation time. A value greater than 1.0 means that the simulation
>     is going faster than real-time, a value lower than 1.0 means that the
>     simulation is going slower than real-time. Note that a too large value
>     may lead to some physics instabilities.

You can set the time scale with `bge.logic.setTimeScale(multiplier)`, where `multiplier` is the number by which the base timestep is scaled.

For example, here's a simple function to toggle between slow-motion and normal-motion:

```
from bge import logic

def toggle_slomo():

    if logic.getTimeScale() < 1:
        logic.setTimeScale(1)
    else:
        logic.setTimeScale(.1)
```

[image]

And here's an example .blend. Note that you'll need a [recent version of blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3438/599) for it to work.

[image]

Comment: it's Jack Sparme from blenderartists.org ^_^ this is very useful, many thanks.

Comment: @JackSparme Glad to hear that :)