# BGE: Why the physics simulation plays different with different time scales?

Tags: game-engine, physics

Actually, many questions in one.

I've downloaded the .blend from [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43228/how-can-i-get-a-bullet-time-effect-slow-motion-in-the-bge), and after playing around with it, it's very easy to notice that the physics simulations results are different with different time scales.

Is this a bug or just the way the simulation works?

If it's how the simulation works, then, the `TimeScale` is not exactly a precise time scale for the physics simulation, it's just an indication of how many physic steps are calculated for each frame?

Does Bullet Physics uses the semi-fixed time step described [in this article](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)? Where floating point precision inlfuences the simulation results each time the simulation is ran.

The [documentation](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_release/bge.logic.html#bge.logic.setTimeScale) says that

> a too large value may lead to some physics instabilities

So, is there a way to correct it?

I'm no game engine expert, so, if I sad something wrong, please correct me.

Thanks in advance.