# How to make an object switch from a animated animation to a dynamic animation in Blender Game Engine?

Tags: animation, game-engine, keyframes

I am having a problem trying to make a bullet type animation where a Sphere (The Bullet) flies forwards really fast with keyframe type animation, then converts to dynamic animation, and shatters a vase.

The Sphere works fine in Cycles Render but has issues in Blender Game. Press P to play the animation, and you'll see what I mean.

After it shoots forward it suddenly stops, instead of going into Blender Dynamics it, slowly falls, and even goes through the floor.

If you need more information please ask.

Make sure you unzip the file. Thank you!

Due to an issue with recording the animation of the sphere I couldn't provide any animation or video.

[image]

Comment: Hi, it would be better that you explain what you did and why it doesn't work (maybe even add an animation or an image), and on this site it is suggested sharing .blend file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then pasting provided link in your question text.

Comment: The attached file need a passwort for download.

Comment: @m.ardito I just updated the information about the problem and the http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ link, won't work for me. The website works just my blend file won't work for some reason. I'm new to Blender Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Dimali I just fixed the link. Please Tell me if it works or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the physics of "Plane.001" to no collision, delete the action actuator and add a python controller, finally [apply force](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=apply%20force#bge.types.KX_GameObject.applyForce) on the bullet.

```
from bge import logic
logic.getCurrentController().owner.applyForce((0,7000,0))
```

[image]

[image]

Press <kbd>P</kbd> and see it!, you will need to take care of when the vase broke.

Comment: It's a little too fast, but I see how you did it! Thanks, I was so disappointed, because I thought I messed up for the 10th time, and there was no solution, but you proved me wrong! Thanks, I don't think I could have done this without your help!

Comment: You can change ``applyForce((0,7000,0))``, i set it like that because in my (old) pc the frame rate was low as 15fps and with 7000 its feels ok, also you can change the speed of animation while playing with ``logic.setTimeScale(0.01 to 1.0)``, check this [https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43228/how-can-i-get-a-bullet-time-effect-slow-motion-in-the-bge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43228/how-can-i-get-a-bullet-time-effect-slow-motion-in-the-bge)

Comment: There is an optional answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go into the game logic menu and add an "Always" Sensor, an "And" Controller, and a "Motion" Actuator. Then just set the speed and you're done!