# Increasing frame rate without speeding up the cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation, frame-rate

I wanted to make my cloth animation less choppy, so I changed the frame rate of the whole scene from 30 to 60 fps:

[image: Settings screenshot]

But that only increased the speed of the whole animation (the animation didn't stretch over time). Can the cloth animation speed be independent of the frame rate? I just want it to be more precise.

Time remapping doesn't seem to work on the simulation.

Comment: Increasing the framerate is not meant as a control for speed. Use time remapping instead. read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Blender 2.78, the speed for a cloth simulation can be adjusted here (Physics tab for a cloth object):

[image]

I did a quick test with a flag running at 24 FPS (normal speed), then changed the FPS to 60 which caused the simulation to run at a higher speed (unrealistic). Changing the "Multiplier" to a lower value reduced the speed while keeping the 60 FPS. If you change the FPS from 24 to 60 (2.5x) you need to have a multiplier of 1/2.5 = 0.4.

It seems the "base factor" is 24.

See the [2.78 release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78#Physics) for more details.