# How to change the speed of an animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes

Okay so after looking around and not finding anything helpful on the matter, I'm going to ask here. Basically what I want to do is speed up my animation of my model walking. Right now it's 39 frames with little adjustments here and there and moving everything manually would risk something jumping out of place.

If anyone is familiar with Windows Movie Maker or most video editing programs, there's an option to increase the speed, thereby changing a 40 second video to 20 seconds in length while doubling the speed.(sorry if I didn't explain that well)

I wanted to know if there was a similar option in Blender to do this in animation. I'm using this model for an upcoming indie game in Unity if that helps. I still consider myself quite new to this, so if screenshots could be included in any helpful answers, it would be greatly appreciated :)

Also due to the model being in an upcoming game, I cannot share or upload it, sorry :(

Comment: You could also go into the Dope Sheet and scale all of the keyframes so they are closer together.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/how-do-i-animate-time and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While adjusting the FPS will make a faster animation, it doesn't help you when you are making a game. In the *Dope Sheet*, select all of your keyframes, press <kbd>S</kbd> and use the mouse to resize the length of your animation.

Comment: Thank you so much, that really saved me so much work! :D I feel pretty silly for not thinking of that XD But again thank you so much for that! :D

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the scene fps as shown below and the animation will be faster:

[image]

Comment: Instead of changing the frame rate, you can use the time rempapping option: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429

Answer (score 0):

alright so for me i was doing a rotation animation and in the graphs editor if you adjust the distance of the specific movement for example say the animation starts at 1 and ends at 250 you will get slow speed animation, if you want the speed to be much faster than head into the graph editor and by adjusting the specific colored line coordinate to a specified object movement left or right you adjust the speed of the object! [image]