# Work in 30 FPS then render in 60

Tags: keyframes, frame-rate

Say I have a project that I've done in 30 FPS.

I now want to re render it for final use at 60 FPS to match my destination project (shot at 60fps).

My current project (at 30FPS) is 2 seconds long. Of course, if I set the project to 60, it will need double the frames. So my current 60 frame project must be "expanded" to 120 frames. If I have key frames at, let's say, 15 and 30 frames (I have more too), is there an easy way to just tell it to scale all the key frames to fit my new project length and frame rate?

Comment: Set the frame rate to the desired output and then compensate the time using Time Remapping Settings Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429

Comment: I see how you might find that to be a duplicate, but I actually want to convert the project to 60FPS, and adjust it as I will be making all projects and such in 60FPS from now on. This is a legacy project (a title) I would like to upgrade, to allow for possible future modifications.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74295/26640

Comment: Maybe open the graph editor with all objects selected, select all points and scale them by 2?