# Where can I set the Vse playback frame rate

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want use VSE to make a short video. The source videos are  25fps so they run slightly slow. Where in the user preferences can you change this. I can't see it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could set the fps to match https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/74284/15543

Answer (score 1):

Make the project match the frame rate of the video.

Go to the **Preferences** window, In the **Dimensions** section set the **Frame Rate** to correspond with that of the video.

[image]

Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6270/1853

Answer (score -1):

[image]

- Add the speed control the strip.  Menu/Add/Effect Strip/Speed Control to the existing strip with clear track above it.
- The new speed,[Multiply Speed] should be (25.0/24.0) . You may try extreme values for testing (.5,2.0)
- Make you strip shorter to hold the new shorter time duration to avoid repeating frames at the end
- Please make adjustments to these suggestions.  I probably wont have time for many edits
- This is a starting point. You may see further references at BSE or elsewhere for fine tuning.