# How do I remap the tracking of 60p footage to 24p project?

Tags: animation, tracking

I've tracked some objects in 60p footage I shot (I did this to get subframe movements for motion blur that might just look a little more realistic, and for the extra accuracy) and objects in my scene to these object solvers.

But now, as I'm doing test renders (in 24p) I see that the motion is slowed down as the footage is tracked on a frame by frame basis.  How do I apply the solver, but change the time scale of the object solver.  I'd rather not have to render the whole scene using time remapping,

Comment: I doubt there is any other option but using [time remapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429) in the Dimensions settings for the scene... Else, you can try solving your object, and then converting the motion to f-curves and scale them to meet your desired framerate... but that sounds more complicated than timeremapping