# Using a 30fps video in a 24fps animation?

Tags: frame-rate

I have a strange situation where I made an animation with a lot of precisely placed sound clips and couldn't figure out why my image texture (with video) and it's audio weren't in sync or playing the whole video in general from start to end.  Then I realized it was 30 frames per second.  Now when I change the original animation which is 24 fps to 30fps, the image texture video plays properly but everything else is completely out of sync.  Is there a way to fix this without having to redo my entire animation's audio in order to get it to accommodate the video texture?

Thanks

Comment: Use the [time remapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/output.html?highlight=time%20remapping) settings in the dimensions section of the properties window.

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429

Comment: @cegaton doesn't that slow down or speed up the overall animation though?  I don't want to have it appear in slow or fast motion.

Comment: You need to slow down your animation so that it conforms to the new time base.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work with the slowing down.  I couldn't figure out the fraction of new and old time remapping.  However, maybe not the best solution but I ended up converting the video used for video texture from 30 to 24 using VLC media player.  That seems to have worked.