# How to increase the time length of the animation without slowing it down?

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm new to blender and have to make a 10-second animation of a walk cycle. The walk cycle I created only lasts for about 2 seconds. How would I be able to increase this to 10 seconds with it looping without increasing/decreasing the speed of the animation? 
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47427/how-can-i-modify-the-frame-rate-without-changing-overall-animation-speed/47429#47429

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/how-do-i-animate-time

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Graph Editor panel, select each "string"/line (these lines represent the way Blender handles the animation data), go to the modifiers tab (This is not the one in the Properties panel, press T if the right-side panel is not visible. You should see a Modifiers tab there.), add a Cycles modifier, and you should the have a repeating animation. Some tweaking may be necessary for it to work correctly. You should need to have the animation repeat five times.