# Rendering Different angles of one frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, camera, smoke-simulation

remember in the first matrix film, where Trinity does that jump kick and time stops? Yeah, and then the camera does a full 360 of here. Well I want that effect.

Now I know you're probably thinking "Why don't you just locRot all the animating for like 100 frames?"... Well because it's got a fire sim in it. And I want the the explosion to start. then "pause" while the cameras fire off in sequence down the room. So it looks like time has stopped. Yes, I could bake the simulation to a specific frame, I know. But I then want the simulation to continue when the camera gets out of the room.

One of you genius's must know a way to do it. Also, I cannot duplicate the scene 100 times (Already 238mb as it is), and then add a camera at every frame. This will cause the universe to explode, I already tried duplicating the scene at it crashed at 8. Also, each frame is on average taking about 15 mins to render. And I can't go to the computer every 15 mins and select the next scene and render the frame.

Any help would be massively appreciated and if your idea works, you'll 100% be credited for it in the animation credits. (short animation student work).

Regards,

Rich

Comment: This might help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/how-do-i-animate-time?noredirect=1&lq=1