# Keyframe number of frames to slow down animation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, keyframes, frame-rate

I have a more or less finished animation.
But now I saw that I want to change (slow down) some parts (objects) of my animation.

[image]

Unfortunately its not easy to change a single part (object), because then the whole animation has to be adjusted too that it matches again the changed part.

So I had the idea that it will be much easier only to increase the number of frames over the part I want to change.

Because then later if I make the video out of all my rendered frames the part with the increased number of frames is slower.
(twice the number of keyframes = 0.5 speed)

Is there a possiblility to keyframe the number of frames or must I split the whole animation in parts and change the amount for each part then ?
Is that a good idea, or will it cause more problems than I see now?

I tried to set a keyframe directly at the fps but that is not possible.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1053/599

Comment: @gandalf3 Yes, thank you, that's what I searched. Is there a way to preview the changes without animation? Because if I have to render the video to see then that maybe something is not like I want is really time consuming.
Should I delete the question, because dublicate?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, what you want to do can be done in the dopesheet (or the curve editor) If you want to slow down a section just drag the keyframes apart.

Comment: Yes in the curve editor would be the best, because there I can see the result without rendering. But the problem is if I change a fiew keyframes in the middle of the animation, than I have to adjust all the keyframes after that too. And that is so much effort.