# Render Animation, Start Frame is doubled

Tags: rendering, animation

Not sure if this is a bug or what, but when I change the `Start Frame` and click `Render Animation`, it starts at a frame double of that which I typed in. If `Start Frame` is `0`, it starts rendering at frame 0. If `Start Frame` is `1`, it starts at frame 2. If `2` starts at 4 and so on...

The funny thing is that this seems to only happen with this project. I started a new fresh one and tested it out and all seems to be working. Also, in all places, it steps forward one frame (as `Frame Step` is `1`), not skipping any.

I'm wondering if I have accidentally set something somewhere without me realizing it.

Blender 2.78c, 30 fps, 1920x1080 at 25% for preview reasons.

EDIT:
The project has some VSE tracks with sound and video, and the scene ontop of that. `Time Remapping` is set to `Old: 100 New: 100`. Also, when given to [Sheep-it](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/) the frames aren't doubled. Yet running blender as command line on my computer the set frame is doubled.

EDIT:
Under Render Properties, Post Processing, there is an option to take the rendered product through the Sequnecer (checkbox named Sequencer). Turning that off did so that the start-frame isn't doubled. Wonder what in the VSE is messing things up? Video Cross Blend? FPS difference?

Besides, that processing isn't necessary at the moment. The video (and audio) was there for reference.

Comment: I have noticed the same behaviour if I add a scene to the VSE, but not if I render the same scene normally. I have described this in detail [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87447/why-must-i-offset-a-scene-in-vse-if-the-start-frame-is-not-0). I'm guessing it's a bug, but waiting for a response before I file a bug report.

Comment: Do you have any [time remapping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1080/599) set?

Comment: gandalf3: Time remapping is 100:100. Though Thailandian may be on to something... I am using the VSE and I have a few tracks of sound and video and the scene on top of that. Wanna know the fun part? Sheep-it Render Farm doesn't double the frames.

Comment: Without a sample file [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)  Or some screen shots that shed some light....  it's a bit of conjecture.   Turning VSE and/or Compositor off in Render Properties > Post Pro will indicate whether it is a VSE/Compositor issue.

Comment: @batFINGER Sorry for the late reply. Been rendering other things in the mean time and gathering points at sheep-it. I went to the Render Properties and looked and found under Post Processing a checkmark in sequencer. Turned that off and now the start-frame isn't doubled. Wonder what in the VSE is messing things up? Video Cross Blend? FPS difference?